# Vinagre has max password length?

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vncviewer, vinagre

When authenticating a user on the remote machine, the form limits the password to 8 characters, why? The password is longer than 8 characters.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNC passwords are limited to 8 characters in length.

References:

- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11130699
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=788014